# Totally new to this - am getting tied in knots!

Tags: wallet

I have purchased £250 worth of Bitcoin - it is now siting in a Coinify account.  I have created my wallet using Electrum - how do I transfer from Coinify to my wallet?  And then what do I do?   Would very much apreciate some help and advice.  thank you

Comment: Welcome to Bitocin.SE! I do not have a Coinify account to be specific but if you want the coins in your wallet you need to get a receive address from your wallet and go to Coinify and send them there.

Comment: Rhank you for responding - I have resolved this now.